# Checking the source of a user's About Me results in an internal server error

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, 500-server-error

Moderators have in certain circumstances access to the revisions of a user's "about me".

[image]

When I click the 'source' link, I get the familiar 500 - Internal Server Error page with "Oops! Something Bad Happened!". Probably because this was a network-wide reset, and there's no source to be shown now?

([link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/history/detail/3052499) for staff to reproduce; the page that errors out is [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/history/detail/3052499/view-source))

Comment: Can confirm that I see the same error message when clicking the "source" link there.